# Loading Images from Dropbox in my app

Tags: android

I am making a activity whereby i ask the user to load image from various sources and showing the selected image on a imageview in a different activity.
I am able to show the image from the camera and gallery but from dropbox it is showing error.
For Camera and gallery i can even query the uri obtained from

intent.getData()

in the onactivityresult method and obtain the Filepath and accordingly even obtain the bitmap and resize it .
But the same is not working for Dropbox. Kindly update what code to use for Dropbox so that all options start working.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

For Dropbox you will need to use their [Android Chooser](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/chooser/android) to choose files from the user's Dropbox account. You will need a Dropbox API key for this. Once you have grabbed the chooser library and your API key it should be fairly easy to implement;

```
private Button mChooserButton;
private DbxChooser mChooser;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mChooser = new DbxChooser(APP_KEY);

    mChooserButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.chooser_button);
    mChooserButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mChooser.forResultType(DbxChooser.ResultType.PREVIEW_LINK)
                    .launch(MainActivity.this, DBX_CHOOSER_REQUEST);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == DBX_CHOOSER_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            DbxChooser.Result result = new DbxChooser.Result(data);
            Log.d("main", "Link to selected file: " + result.getLink());

            // Handle the result
        } else {
            // Failed or was cancelled by the user.
        }
    } else if (requestCode == GALLERY) {
        // If your request was from the user gallery
        Log.d("main", "Link to selected file: " + data.getData());
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: THANKS FOR YOUR ANSWER. HOWEVER I DO NOT WANT TO SHOW CUSTOM DIALOG FOR USER TO SELECT OPTION .I AM ABLE TO SHOW DROPBOX OPTION AND GET TO SHOW ALL FILES FROM DROPBOX .THE FILE GETS DOWNLOADED BUT I AM NOT ABLE TO USE THE URI TO SHOW THE IMAGE IN MY IMAGEVIEW.